# Drupal 7 - output menu items with links

Tags: menu, drupal-7, icons, themes

I am using the menu icons module and get the following array

[image]

Can I tap into this using the theme function or is it best to itterate though and gnerate my menu?

If so how?

Comment: Would you mind to change the title from `Drupla 7` to `Drupal 7`?

Comment: I need to output the menu icon in the menu. Thanks.